# Removing conjugate tuples from a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple is a tuple as well. For each outer tuple, I have a conjugate tuple. By this I mean that if I have (a,b) in the list then I also have (b,a) as well. What I want is to remove the conjugate tuples from the list.

To give you a concrete example of my list here it is:

`[((1,2,1,0),(5,2,1,0)),((2,4,4,0),(2,5,4,0)),((2,5,4,0),(2,4,4,0)),((3,1,1,0),(3,3,2,0)),((3,3,2,0),(3,1,1,0)),((5,1,7,0),(8,1,7,0)),((5,2,1,0),(1,2,1,0)),((5,5,8,0),(8,5,8,0)),((5,6,6,0),(8,6,8,0)),((5,9,9,0),(8,9,9,0)),((6,3,5,0),(6,8,9,0)),((6,8,9,0),(6,3,5,0)),((7,7,6,0),(9,7,6,0)),((8,1,7,0),(5,1,7,0)),((8,5,8,0),(5,5,8,0)),((8,6,8,0),(5,6,6,0)),((8,9,9,0),(5,9,9,0)),((9,7,6,0),(7,7,6,0))]`

The result after removing the conjugate tuples should be:

`[((1,2,1,0),(5,2,1,0)),((2,4,4,0),(2,5,4,0)),((3,1,1,0),(3,3,2,0)),((5,1,7,0),(8,1,7,0)),((5,5,8,0),(8,5,8,0)),((5,6,6,0),(8,6,8,0)),((5,9,9,0),(8,9,9,0)),((6,3,5,0),(6,8,9,0)),((7,7,6,0),(9,7,6,0)),]`

I have tried for hours with no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Each tuple is a tuple as well." You mean each tuple consists of tuples as well.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? That is do you want a hint or do you want a solution?

Comment: Yes. May be the example I posted is better than my wording :)

Comment: @jpath : No it is not a home work :) I am nearly 60 years old. I m trying to solve jigsaw sudoko, and I needed to remove duplicates.

Comment: @jpath: if my list seems cryptic, then these represent cells in a jigsaw sudoko. Each cell is of type (Int,Int,Int,Int) repressing the row, column, region and value of the cell. I have written a function that given a grid, I obtained the cells which have same potential values. The example is such a list of such cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Each element of the tuple is a tuple as well"

```
removeConj xs = foldl f [] xs
  where f b a = if (elem (snd a, fst a) b) then b else (a:b)
```

Comment: Well, thanks. but I tried it, and it gave me the same list, i.e, it didn't remove conjugates.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. Interesting, though is that the order of the resulting list is the reverse of the list that jpath solution produces. I think I can retain the order by applying the reverse function.

Comment: As a side note, is there anyway in Haskell to measure the time that two function take to perform a task. For example how can I compare if ja solution is faster or slower than jpath solution?

Comment: I know that using ghci to benchmark functions is not accurate. However, I used :set +s to compare the solutions I got. The results are:

(0.06 secs, 272,840 bytes) -- for removeConj
(0.07 secs, 277,416 bytes) -- for nubTuples

p.s: I used this on my sample which doesn't provide real indicators.

Answer (score 5):

First we can generalise the type to the following:

```
nubTuples :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
```

However, to make things efficient and easier let's also ask for an `Ord` instance for `a`. Why does this make things easier? Because now we can transform our tuples into an ordered normal form. Then we can simply `nub . sort`. The below implemenation actually just sorts and nubs based on that representation, so that `nubTuples [(2,1)] = [(2,1)]` and not `[(1,2)]`.

```
import Data.List (sortOn, nubBy)
import Data.Tuple (swap)

nubTuples :: Ord a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
nubTuples = nubBy unorderedCompare . sortOn orderTuple
  where orderTuple (x,y)
          | x < y = (x,y)
          | otherwise = (y,x)
        unorderedCompare x y = x == y || swap x == y
```

Note that this changes the order and removes duplicates:

```
nubTuples [(3,4),(1,2),(1,2)] = [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

As for changing the order we can fix this by using the `nubWith` function from `Data.Discrimination` in the [`discrimination`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.2.1/docs/Data-Discrimination-Grouping.html) package. Then our code would become the following:

```
 import Data.Discrimination (nubWith, Grouping)

 nubTuples :: (Ord a, Grouping a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
 nubTuples = nubWith orderTuple
   where orderTuple (x,y)
           | x < y = (x,y)
           | otherwise = (y,x)
```

This doesn't require sorting, keeps the order intact and is maximally lazy (which is often very important for performance). It still removes duplicates though.

You can simply derive a `Grouping` instance for any of your types likes this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Discrimination
import GHC.Generics

data A = A deriving Generic
instance Grouping A
```

Note that there is no instance of `Grouping` for 4-tuples. This would be a way to work around it:

```
nubFourTuples :: (Grouping a, Ord a, Grouping b, Ord b,
                  Grouping c, Ord c, Grouping d, Ord d)
              => [((a,b,c,d),(a,b,c,d))] -> [((a,b,c,d),(a,b,c,d))]
nubFourTuples = (fmap . both) reassociate . nubTuples . (fmap . both) associate
   where associate (w,x,y,z) = ((w,x),(y,z))
         reassociate ((w,x),(y,z)) = (w,x,y,z)
         both f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

Comment: many thanks @jpath. it worked. The order of the resulting list is not important to me.

Comment: @HassanShahin You are welcome. I've still added another version that keeps the order and has the added benefit of being lazy.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed. Thanks again @jpath

Comment: This is great. But you are moving to the more advanced stuff. I am only a old beginner :). Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I already felt a bit guilty when writing `join bimap` and the really long type of `nubFourTuples`. And the whole `discrimination` is probably already too much as well for a beginner.